# wordpress injection scripts & images finding

Tags: wordpress, security, plugins, code-injection

My wordpress site was injected some unwanted scripts & images. Right now nearly 25 plugins available on my site. So i am not able to review each plugin folders & sub folders.

Please let me know any wordpress plugins available for this issue (inject) finding.

OR any other alternative solutions also please let know

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to go through the different parts of WordPress (Theme, plugins, WordPress itself) to locate the script. I would start by turning off the current theme. If the code still on the page, the script is not in the Theme. Continue by turning off all plugins, etc... until you find the location.

I think it takes less than 15 minutes to find out where the script is located.

Also maybe this plugin can help you https://www.wordfence.com